# How is "used space" calculated on Windows 7 NTFS, and how can I tell what occupies space?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

I have two Win7 laptops, and I'm comparing disk usage using different programs and getting different answers.

Below are the figures; the first comes from a right-click on the disk in Windows Explorer and selecting "Properties" and reading off the "bytes" figure (not the "G" figure that evidently uses the 1024 bytes-per-K type reckoning); the second comes from a program I wrote that goes recursively through the directories and counts up all the file sizes per each directory.

```
WExp  SpaceCheck  
217G    59.9G    Machine 1
273G   144.2G    Machine 2
```

Some of it, I expect, is from the difference between bytes in the file (which SpaceCheck counts) and space occupied on the disk (which WinExplorer may be counting). But I don't think that would account for such a large difference on either machine, but especially machine 1.

I do have folder options set to show me 'hidden and system' files; I've tried using WExp to tell me about large files on the disk of machine 1, sorting for anything from the last month or two, but haven't seen anything significant.

I'm hoping someone can give me other things to check and/or a way to chase down where the disk space is being used up.

Comment: Did you check the shadow copy storage? Was your program running as admin?

Comment: Gosh, didn't think of that -- only vaguely knew about shadow storage. I just checked machine 2 with "vssadmin list shadowstorage", and its usage is 25G, so that doesn't account for all the difference, even there. Probably my program does not count that. One article I read on it indicates that it is supposed to restrict itself to 5% normally. Thanks for pointing it out, but I don't think it's the whole answer.

Comment: Well, now I've checked the other machine, and shadowstorage is 136G -- that accounts for all the difference. Somehow the 'allocated amount' on that machine is 100% instead of 5%. I don't know what that means or how to change it yet, but it's an excellent place to start looking. Thanks! (If you want to put this in an answer, I'll accept it).

Comment: Can you tell me where the shadow copy storage is located? Is it a file, or set of files, on the disk in some folder?

Comment: Shadow copies are in the System Volume Information folder https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2008/07/03/ntfs-misreports-free-space/

Comment: @DavidMarshall That’s not true. That are just Symlinks System Restore creates. Because it’s a delta snapshot mechanism, it’s stored “everywhere”.

Comment: @rcook have you used TreeSize to see which folders use most space?

Comment: Discovered TreeSize through responses to this question (there is an answer mentioning it), hadn't known about it before. It is a slightly-more-complete version of the program I wrote myself. I got my question answered in a comment, so finding this tool was just gravy. Thanks!

Comment: @rcook  ok, if it helped you accept the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I was kind of hoping the original answering person would post as an answer so I could accept that. I'll wait a while longer for him to do that.

Comment: @rcook Nobody except me in the answer mentioned TreeSize. So I have no idea what you talk about. But in the future I'll no longer help you. Bye

Answer (score 0):

When you open Explorer and select properties, Windows reads the free space from the [NTFS bitmap metafile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2008/07/03/ntfs-misreports-free-space/) by [calling DeviceIoControl](https://codeistry.wordpress.com/2015/01/01/use-of-fsctl_get_volume_bitmap-to-read-bitmap-file-from-ntfs-refs-volume/) with `FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP` IOCTL. Selecting all files/folders in explorer and showing properties, scan all files/folders. But Windows skips here hidden files/folders and folders where your current user doesn't have read permissions (System Volume Information folder for example).

You should use [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) (run it as admin) to see which folders take most space:

[image]